# 'Ui_Form' object has no attribute 'COLUMN_5'

Tags: python

I changed `self.COLUMN_5` to `self.ROW` but still the same error so it's all on COLUMN_5

I keep getting the error

> 'Ui_Form' object has no attribute 'COLUMN_5'

This is my code:

```
def    double_table(self):
        for currentItem in  self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
            self.COLUMN_5 = currentItem.column()
            self.ROW_5 = currentItem.row()
        #if you check on column (i,4) I want to get result   
        if  (self.COLUMN_5 == 4):
            self.l = self.tableWidget.item(self.ROW_5,2)
            self.w = self.tableWidget.item(self.ROW_5,3)
            self.l = self.l.text()
            self.w=self.w.text()
            ##print(self.l,'  ',self.w,' ',type(self.w),' ',type(self.l))
            #Multiplication of two column at the same row 
            if  (self.l!='' and self.l!=None  and self.w!='' and self.w!=None):
                self.m=float(self.l)*float(self.w)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(self.ROW_5,4,QTableWidgetItem(str(self.m)))
            else:
                self.tableWidget.setItem(self.ROW_5,4,QTableWidgetItem("Error"))
        else:
            pass
```

I want to multiply two columns at the same row and show the result on last column on that row

Comment: What leads you to believe that `Ui_Form` has an attribute called `CULOMN_5`?

Comment: @fountainhead i made Variable and named it CULUMN_5

Comment: Are you spelling it correctly?

Comment: @fountainhead i made it on this line self.CULOMN_5=currentItem.column()

Comment: @fountainhead self.CULOMN_5 is just a variable that has amount  of  currentItem.column

Comment: Perhaps it never entered the `for` loop and therefore never executed `self.CULOMN_5=currentItem.column()`. Did you check whether it entered the `for` loop?

Comment: @fountainhead i know if i put 'if ' in ' for ' loop it will be ok but it has effect on my code idk how to create a variable in for and use it out of it

Comment: I think you mis-understood my comment above. If `self.CULOMN_5=currentItem.column()` is executed, then the attribute called `CULOMN_5` will get created on the `self` object, and you won't be getting this error. The problem I'm suspecting is that that assignment statement is **not** getting executed, because (I suspect that) the `for` loop is not being entered at all. The necessary condition for entering the `for` loop, is not being met.